# SQLite database allowing null values

Tags: android, sqlite

I use the following code to create database in my android application. Actually, In need to copy data from another table to this table. It only copied 10868 records, but the original table contains 24000 records.

I checked and finally found at the 10869 record, there is a null value on one of the field. But I didn't specify "not null " during table creation. But this table caan't accept null values.

```
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE1 =
          "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE2 + " ("
          + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
          + KEY_RCODE + " text, "
          + KEY_RNAME + " text);";
```

Is there any other ways to allow columns to accept null values?  I really confused

Edit: Android code

```
try
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://moberp.svsugar.com:8080/androidservlt/ryotmas");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Buffer Error"+"Error converting result"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        contacts = jObj.getJSONArray("get");
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
            rcode = c.getString("rcode");
            rname = c.getString("rname");
            radapter.insert(rcode, rname);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Ryot BackUp completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: They *do* accept nulls at sqlite level (except the primary key column, of course), so the problem should be elsewhere (like handling nulls improperly on java side)

Comment: I'll post my android code

Comment: I see you're retreiving the values from an HttpPost rather than directly from another SQLITE database.
Could it be that the values with nulls in them aren't in the response at all?

Comment: Null values are in the response. I saw. You can also see by copy and paste the httppost in your browser

Comment: Ok, so far so good then.
Is there a try/catch handler in `radapter.insert` ?
If there is, does the catch log an error?

Comment: No there is no try catch

Comment: ... hmmm tricky.
So you do get to see the Toast that says "Ryot BackUp completed" when you sync?

Comment: No. I saw "no value for rname"

Comment: Then your problem is not in SQLITE ;)

Comment: i don't see the part where you insert in database, in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if the values you are retreiving from the JSON object actually have a value.

If they do not have a value that they can cast to the type you are retreiving, they will throw a JSONException.

You can easily do this check with `IsNUll`

```
JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
            rcode = c.getString("rcode");

            if(!c.isNull("rname"))
            {
              rname = c.getString("rname");
            }
            else
            {
              rname = ""; //or rname = null, whatever you want
            }
            radapter.insert(rcode, rname);
        }
```

Comment: sorry, looks like i misread. The IsNull function should be on the JsonObject (see updated answer)

Comment: Try to keep in mind that i'm not sure which of these is nullable 
(you should be able to tell that yourself from the dataset)

This kind of handling should be put in place for every nullable field you are trying to retreive from json.